# Grub2 not install on Surface 3 (non-pro)

Tags: grub2, surface

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16 0 4, and I've gotten as far as being asked to try or install, if I install, it will either error out when install grub, or when it asks to reboot, it will freeze on shutdown. If I try, I can get in and try Boot-Repair or something, but it will again error out on Grub2 install. If I go ahead and restart anyway's, it will boot to the stupid surface 3 bios crappy thing asking me about like 4 options, secureboot and what to boot from so on.

Here is my pastebin report Boot-Repair told me to copy and use in a question here.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26295410/

This is really annoying me, and I hope it can be resolved.

P.S. I'm new to grub, and sort of new to ubuntu in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your partitions ahead of time. Boot into ubuntu, select live, and open gparted. Create the following, in the ext4 format, and make sure to label them :

- /home - where your files will go. Your main workspace area
- /root - your root partition, where ubuntu is installed to.
- /linux-swap - this is used when your RAM flows over, to prevent crashes.

Linux-swap should be half your ram, but maximum 4 gigabytes. /root is good at about 15 GiB, and /home can be as big as you want it. **Make sure secure boot is off, as well as fast boot.** Then click manual installation, and select the partitions you've created. It should work from there. Good luck!

Comment: When I tried to make the partition in GParted, and then tried to install it to them, it says there is no defined Root directory, cannot install.

Comment: @JaredCollins -- the root diresctory is "/" not "/root" ... this is likely the error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm such a noob could you explain a  little more? i can set the mount location of a partition to "/" but i can't for home, im not sure what you mean, sorry.. could you take a screen shot of exactly what gparted shoudl look like?

Comment: Sorry I think I figured it out, because I setup the partition like you said, I clicked next and it was going to install and such.. but battery died so now I'm mad.. however, at the bottom, it asks where to put the bootloader, WHERE, should I put it? under what partition?

Comment: It goes under "/". You need to mark the root partition as bootable.